# how does cv::TermCriteria work in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use the opencv function `cv::cornerSubPix()`  for that I need another one, the `cv::TermCriteria`  my question is about the last parameter of this function :

```
cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER +
                cv::TermCriteria::EPS,
                50, // max number of iterations
                0.0001)); // min accuracy
```

what does the min accuracy here mean?

Comment: I see the answers here are not really detailed. Did you find a nice explanation about TermCriteria? I'm trying to understand it right now and I do not find any good explanations.

Comment: @Crash-ID   :\ I didn't sorry, I'm not using OpenCV anymore so wish you good luck with your project

Comment: Okey, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 10):

The structure of **TermCriteria** is

```
TermCriteria(

int type, // CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, or both

int maxCount,

double epsilon
);
```

Typically we use the **TermCriteria()** function to generate the structure we need. The
first argument of this function is either **CV_TERMCRIT_ITER** or **CV_TERMCRIT_EPS**, which tells the algorithm that we want to terminate either after some number of iterations or when
the convergence metric reaches some small value (respectively). The next two arguments
set the values at which one, the other, or both of these criteria should terminate the algorithm.

The reason we have both options is so we can set the type to **CV_TERMCRIT_ITER |
CV_TERMCRIT_EPS** and thus stop when either limit is reached.

Answer (score 4):

The exact meaning of the epsilon term depends on the algorithm for which the termination criteria is intended. (See pp 299-300 of the [Learning OpenCV](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf) book for some more details on `cvTermCriteria`)

Here, specifically, from the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cornersubpix#cornersubpix):

> ... the process of corner position refinement stops either after
>   `criteria.maxCount` iterations or when the corner position moves by
>   less than `criteria.epsilon` on some iteration.

So the epsilon term specifies the accuracy you require in your subpixel values, for example a value of `0.0001` means you are asking for subpixel values down to an accuracy of 1/10000th of a pixel. (See p 321 of the [Learning OpenCV](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf) book)

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV docs for TermCriteria is here http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#termcriteria Last parameter is epsilon. Some algorithm are iterative and stop when they reach desired accuracy.

Look for the implementation of the cv::cornerSubPix() function here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/cornersubpix.cpp